# Is there an efficient algorithm in JavaScript to find the number of distinct arrays within a larger array set?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Given the following array

```
let array = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [2, 1]]
```

I want to return the number of distinct arrays in this set. So the example above should return `3`. How do I achieve this? I tried the code below, but it does not give the right answer

```
let distinct = 0
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

  for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length - i; j++) {
    let difference = ingredients[i].filter(x => !array[j].includes(x))
     if (difference.length > 0) {
       distinct += 1;   
     } 
   }
 }

 return distinct;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### If the order inside a sub item matters

Use `Array.map()` to convert each sub-array into a string (I've used `String()` as [suggested by @trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59497764/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-in-javascript-to-find-the-number-of-distinct-arr/59497803#comment105168718_59497803)), create a Set from the array to remove duplicates, and get the size of the Set:

```js
const array = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

const distinct = new Set(array.map(String))

console.log(distinct.size)
```

### If the order doesn't matter

Sort each sub item, and then convert to string:

```js
const array = [[2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

const distinct = new Set(array.map(o => String(o.sort())))

console.log(distinct.size)
```

Comment: I think `JSON.stringify` is enough to distinguish arrays, no need to use `join`.

Comment: @VLAZ though join might be slightly more efficient? if that even makes a difference, though.

Comment: You could even just `map(String)`, if it is guaranteed that the input consists of things that don't have the delimiter. That will do a `join` internally, so at least as efficient.

Comment: The important part is getting a string. I like the `String` suggested by @trincot.

Comment: Sometimes JS can look really nice, it reads like "a new Set of the array mapped to Strings".

Comment: I was looking for an algorithm not dependent on the order of the array items. For example if I add the array [2, 1] I should still be able to get 3. But I am getting 4. I want [2, 1] to be indistinguishable with [1, 2]

Comment: BTW, normally it's important to sort numbers numerically,  like: `o.sort((a, b) => a - b)`. Here, we can "get away" with sorting them alphabetically, like: `o.sort()`, because we don't require a meaningful sort order, just a consistent one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could have tried. Try converting the inner arrays to a string, then filter the dupes and parse the string again

```js
var pp =  [[1, 2], [1, 2] ,[3, 4] ,[5, 6]];
var distict = pp.map(ar=>JSON.stringify(ar))
  .filter((itm, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(itm) === idx)
  .map(str=>JSON.parse(str));

console.log(distict.length);
```

Comment: I was looking for an algorithm not dependent on the order of the array items. For example if I add the array [2, 1] I should still be able to get 3. But I am getting 4. I want [2, 1] to be indistinguishable with [1, 2]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check your algorithm at all, just corrected your syntax. Is this what you meant to write?:

```js
let array = [
  [1, 2],[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]
];

console.log(countDistinctArrays(array));

function countDistinctArrays(parentArray) {
  let distinct = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < parentArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < parentArray.length - i; j++) {
      let difference = parentArray[i].filter(x => !parentArray[j].includes(x))
      if (difference.length > 0) {
        distinct += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return distinct;
}
```

Comment: Well done for analyzing and fixing the original algorithm, though such a simple operation can be done in just one line of code. Deserved +1 for fixing the original code, though.